# OpenCV quantization sample code not running

Tags: python, opencv, k-means, quantization

I'm running the quantization sample code found [in the OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_kmeans/py_kmeans_opencv/py_kmeans_opencv.html#goal), and it's throwing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "QuantizeTest.py", line 13, in <module>
ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Z,K,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Here's the code itself:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('Sample.jpg')
Z = img.reshape((-1,3))

# convert to np.float32
Z = np.float32(Z)

# define criteria, number of clusters(K) and apply kmeans()
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
K = 8
ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Z,K,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

# Now convert back into uint8, and make original image
center = np.uint8(center)
res = center[label.flatten()]
res2 = res.reshape((img.shape))

cv2.imshow('res2',res2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Z,K,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
```

to:

```
ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Z,K,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
```

(Deleted `None`)